# redux-saga execute generator from classic callback function

Tags: react-native, onesignal, redux-saga

I'm creating a ReactNative app using redux-saga, but I have some problem to use some of the plugins in combination with redux-saga.

My code looks like that. 
How can I execute the IdsAvailable generator??

```
function *IdsAvailable(pushToken, userId){
   yield put({ type: 'PUSH_TOKEN_AVAILABLE', pushToken })
}

OneSignal.addEventListener('ids', function * ({ pushToken, userId }){
    // this of course dosn't work
    IdsAvailable(pushToken, userId);

})
```

Comment: have you found an answe?

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with redux-saga whatsoever but I guess you are trying to achieve something like this?

```
function *IdsAvailable(pushToken, userId){
   yield put({ type: 'PUSH_TOKEN_AVAILABLE', pushToken })
}

OneSignal.addEventListener('ids', function * ({ pushToken, userId }){
    // just call next() and the generator will yield the next value
    // (in this case call the put method)
    IdsAvailable(pushToken, userId).next();

})
```